# Invalid JSON response on Laravel 5.2 and yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle

Tags: laravel, datatables

My question is very similar with [Yajra Datatables Package for Laravel deosnt work properly with laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236671/yajra-datatables-package-for-laravel-deosnt-work-properly-with-laravel-5-2)

I get Invalid JSON response on Chrome but I couldn't view the HTTP call response.

Here is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Office;
use Datatables;

class OfficeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('offices.index', ['page_title' => 'Jabatan']);
    }

    public function data()
    {
        $offices = Office::select(['id', 'title']);

        return Datatables::of($offices)->make(true);
    }

...
```

My script

```
$(function() {
    $('#offices-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('offices.data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'title', name: 'title' }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: you can view the response of your ajax call in chrome dev tool (network tab)

Comment: @SylvainGuilbert I tried but chrome always tell me: This request has no response data available

Comment: just copy paste your ajax url in an another page

Comment: @SylvainGuilbert I did and it return nothing

Comment: well.... that's why

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check what your function exactly returns. So I would suggest you to modify it like that first

```
public function data()
{
    $offices = Office::select(['id', 'title']);

    dd(Datatables::of($offices)->make(true));
}
```

And then go to the URL aimed to this function in your browser or use inspector to see what you get there. I think it will help you figure out whats wrong.

If it will show expected result try to modify your function like this:

```
public function data()
{
    $offices = Office::select(['id', 'title']);

    return new JsonResponse(Datatables::of($offices)->make(true));
}
```

And don't forget to add

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
```

statement before your controller class definition.

Comment: I did your suggestion but the result still the same. FYI, I found no error in Laravel log file as well as NGINX error.log

Comment: So what dd(); function shows you if you open the url in your browser?